# Anaconda can't open no error message nothing

Tags: python, anaconda

i have a problem with my anaconda navigator. If i click the icon on window 10 nothing is happen. No error nothing. I reinstalled the whole anaconda distribution but the problem still exists.

Maybe someone can help me. Its a little bit tricky for me. The other solution is to set up a new win 10 on my pc but there should be a other option.

Short summary

If I open anaconda navigator nothing happen.
I also set the environment variable to path

Comment: Can you use other parts of Anaconda normally (like typing `conda`in the command propmt?)

Comment: yeah this is working, I laso started update via conda prompt. But the main window isnt opening.

Comment: anyone have an idea?

Comment: nobody had the same problem like me? I know it worked somedays but at the moment nothing happend.

Comment: hmm still no answer? Maybe i did something wrong? :O

Comment: What happens when you enter `anaconda-navigator` in the terminal? Does it give an error message?

Comment: (base) C:\Users\nox>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

Comment: thats the error i get

Comment: pls add stuff like that to your question, not in comments. Besides that, install the missing module with `conda install pyside`